# How do I convert long sentences from speech to text using WebSpeech API?

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, webspeech-api

So far I have been able to convert about 4-5 words from speech to text using the Webspeech API.

my source looks like this;

```
var SpeechRecognition = SpeechRecognition || webkitSpeechRecognition
var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
recognition.lang = 'en-US';
recognition.interimResults = false;
recognition.maxAlternatives = 1;
document.body.onclick = function() {
  recognition.start();
}

recognition.onresult = function(event) {
  var i = event.results.length-1;

  var j = event.results[i].length-1;
  var text = event.results[i][j].transcript;

  diagnostic.textContent = 'Result received: ' + text + '.';
  console.log('Confidence: ' + event.results[i][j].confidence);
}

recognition.onspeechend = function() {
  recognition.stop();
}

recognition.onerror = function(event) {
  diagnostic.textContent = 'Error occurred in recognition: ' + event.error;
}
```

So when I say **anymore words than 5-6** I get an `Error occurred in recognition: network error`.

if I say **less words** it **works fine**.

I also tried setting the `recognition.continuous` variable for what it's worth it did not work.

**is there no way I can convert long speeches to text in browser using a free speech to text API?**

if so point me in the direction.

**or should I convert recorded audio to text in the backend by sending audio to the backend? if so how to do that?**

Comment: Can't repro on Chrome 70 on macOs. Long sentences are gotten without a problem (well, not saying it's 100% accurate, but given my awful English pronunciation :-P).

Comment: are you saying that you were able to convert long sentences to text without anything added new in the above code I have put?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean.

Comment: Even I am using chrome 70 and am not able to get past 5 words. Should I add any specific grammar to recognition object?

Comment: can you provide me code?